# SMTP in Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

I have wrote a Google script to send an email on a certain time.
So right now it works properly sending from `"example@gmail.com"`. Currently `example@gmail.com's` has access to send/receive email from `mail@example.com`. But the script doesn't work when I want to schedule an email from `mail@example.com`

I went through Google's documentation `GmailApp.sendEmail(message.getTo(), message.getSubject(), body, options);` and I saw that `sendEmail` doesn't have a from. I am wondering how I can fix this problem.

I've tried making it the draft email from `mail@example.com` tried setting the default user to `mail@example.com` but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have aliases. This is how you send as alias

```
var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases();
Logger.log(aliases);
GmailApp.sendEmail(message.getTo(), message.getSubject(), body, {'from': aliases[0]});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code is sending a message that is currently in your `drafts` folder, you can use the technique from [How to send a draft email using google apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27206595/how-to-send-a-draft-email-using-google-apps-script/27215474#27215474) to send a message preserving the alias in the `From:` field.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send email over SMTP in Google Scripts.

However, you can make POST requests using [`UrlFetchApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params), so you may be able to use an email provider with an API. There are a number of providers with free plans if you don't send many emails (although these free plans rarely allow you to pass SPF/DMARC, so it may be worth upgrading).

Try something like this (obviously will vary depending on your provider):

```js
const API_ENDPOINT = 'https://api.example.com/email';
const FROM_ADDRESS = 'from@example.com';
const API_TOKEN = 'YOUR_API_TOKEN';

let emailAddress = 'to@example.com';

let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
  API_ENDPOINT,
  {
    'method': 'post',
    'headers': {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Basic: ${API_TOKEN}`,
    },
    'payload': JSON.stringify({
      'From': FROM_ADDRESS,
      'To': emailAddress,
      'Subject': 'POSTing email from Google Scripts',
      'TextBody': 'You have succesfully POSTed email Google Scripts',
    })
  }
);
console.log(response.getContentText());
```